# Start-Process with alternative credential in a remote session

Tags: powershell, remote-access, powershell-3.0, start-process

all,
I believe this scenario sounds indeed odd, but I do need your help on this.
First I use

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName myComputerName -Credential domain\user1`

to remote to a third machine from my dev machine. I got a prompt like **[myComputername]: PS C:\Users\user\**. Then I try to Start-Process with another user, say domain\user2. However it failed, although the executable path fed to the Start-Process is full under control of domain\user2. I suppose there is no permission problem on this.  For example

`Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList "-command`" & {whoami} `"" -Credential domain\user2 -WorkingDirectory workingdirectory`

It wouldn't print the domain\user2. And it would if you run this command after remote desktop to the test machine. Anyone knows the root cause and the fix of this?
Thanks & Regards,
Jingfei

Comment: I'm running into this same difficulty where user1 for me is an account on a different domain, and user2 is an account with sql permissions I need on a database in that different domain. Interesting that this never got answered; doesn't seem like this is so out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the dreaded Powershell Remoting Second Hop blues.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj853299.aspx

CredSSP:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309365(v=vs.85).aspx

Delegating credentials to a runspace:

http://www.vinithmenon.com/2012/11/delegated-administration-in-windows.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to add something, the 'Enter-PSSession' is not controlled by me in our product scenario which means I need to Start-Process with domain\user2 under a domain\user1 PS session. Your solutions are all to change the properties or parameters of the first step, i.e. 'Enter-PSSession'

Comment: Those are the only solutions I know of.  The target (Enter-PSSession) machine will not delegate your connection credentials to another machine unless it is explicitly configured to do so, either by using CredSSP authentication or by using PSSession delegation.